# What kind of alternatives to Google staticmap exist?

Tags: geospatial

I need to get a bunch (>100.000) of static satellite images around a specific spot.
The way I do it now is simple: I send a request with `longitude` and `latitude` to Google staticmap API, like that:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=39.87514383009362 -83.09151320633832&zoom=19&size=1000x1000&maptype=satellite&key=MY_API_KEY
```

The example is here: https://codepen.io/chapkovski/full/mdWaxgp

The problem is that some satellite images by Google Maps are pretty old (sometimes 2 or 3 years old).

Any ideas of a similar API with the comparable pricing (Google charges $2 for 1000 images), but with more recent data?

Answer (score 0):

https://staticmapmaker.com/ provides a quick way to generate API calls for 7 different static map providers, including Google maps. I think they are all paid services but differ in the baselayers they provide, etc. So you need an API key for each but the preview option allows you to see the basic map image they output.